# django authentication stored password reconstruction

Tags: django, django-authentication

I have a django login mechanism that uses django to store hashed version of the passwords. Then I have a desktop app that needs to authenticate with the server. However, I don't know how to calculate that hash value...

right now, I'm posting to my login page, client's username and passowrd (without hashing) which is super unsecure. (running alpha)  I know an alternative would be to hash and unhash before sending and after receiving with a new hash function but I'd rather use the same, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking about it wrong.

1. The hash is usualy stored in format `<function>$<hash>`
2. The `<function>` used are widely known algorithms
3. You can easily find the code behind these `<function>` in django
4. Even if you sent the hash from client, it can be intercepted the same way as plaintext password can and the attacker can use it to gain access to the API provided to the client that uses it.
5. I'm not quite sure about this point, but I think the hash is salted with `SECRET_KEY` which you would need to provide to the client in order to create the hash, therefore leaking very important information.
6. Hashing is one way function, you can't unhash it afterwards.
7. If you wanna add security, use SSL or other scheme based on asymetric cryptography like gnupg or ssh keys.

Comment: I wouldn't need to provide the client the secret_key. it will be only inside the desktop app code. if i know how django does 5, i should be fine i think

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why posting an un-hashed password from your desktop app would be any more insecure than doing so from a browser, which of course is what you do every time you log into a website. It's exactly the same mechanism, and should be done in exactly the same way.

In any case, as yaccz points out, you can't reproduce the hashing mechanism without giving the desktop app access to your secret key in some way. Even if it isn't immediately accessible, just being there on the client's computer is a far greater security risk than the one you are imagining.